# Click event for Button with Control Template

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I have a button with a simple Control Template:

```
<Page.Resources>
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="LButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock FontSize="52" FontWeight="Thin" 
                   TextAlignment="Right"
                   Text="Hello"
                   Margin="30 0 0 30"    
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
        Style="{StaticResource launchButton}"                 
        Template="{StaticResource LButton}"
        Margin="0 10 10 0"
        x:Name="LoyalityButton" Opacity="0" Click="L_Click"/>
```

But the event click rises only when I click on TextBlock.  What do I need to do to make the click event raises event I touch to empty space on the button ?

Comment: set Border's Background, now it is transparent, and transparency means not visible to hit test.

Comment: Thanks. It helps. Can you create the answer and I close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Border's Background property, now it is transparent, and transparency means not visible to hit test.